# How can i apply a style to custom preference TimePicker?

Tags: android, xml, material-design

I want to change the textcolor using a custom style for my TimePicker preference but i can't seem to override the default theme.

Here is my theme resource file:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.Posture" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/purple_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/grey_dark</item>
</style>
```

I'm using PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat and DialogPreference to create the custom TimePicker.

Here is the layout i inflate in the Dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TimePicker
    style="@style/TimePickerStyle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/timePicker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I tried creating a style but when i use it in the timepicker it doesn't gets applied.

```
<style name="TimePickerStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TimePicker
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/timePicker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/TimePickerStyle"/>
```

and style:

```
<style name="TimePickerStyle">
    <item name="android:numbersTextColor">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:numbersSelectorColor">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:numbersBackgroundColor">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that i tried that but it does nothing, i also tried android:theme and in the preview it works but then when i run the app it does't change